# C programming Data structures User Input Fail to initialize a struct type Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, data-structures

In the .h file I have,

```
typedef struct {
int month;
int day;
}Date;

typedef struct {
char courseName[30];
char assignName[30];
int points;
Date duedate;
}QueData;
```

And this below is in the .c file

```
int main(int argc, char argv[]) {

QuePtr priority_hw;
NodePtr FrontNode;
priority_hw = initQueue(10);

    char UserInput1[30], UserInput2[20];
int UserInput3, UserInput4, UserInput5;

printf("Please enter 1st Course name \n");
scanf("%s", &UserInput1);
printf("Please enter 1st Assignment name \n");
scanf("%s", &UserInput2);
printf("Please enter 1st Assignment's points  \n");
scanf("%d", &UserInput3);
printf("Please enter 1st Assignment's duedate month  \n");
scanf("%d", &UserInput4);
printf("Please enter 1st Assignment's duedate day  \n");
scanf("%d", &UserInput5);


printf("Entered Name: %s\n", UserInput1);
printf("Entered Website:%s", UserInput2);

Date duedate1 = { UserInput4, UserInput5 };
QueData assignment1 = { UserInput1, UserInput2, UserInput3, duedate1 };
```

But red line appears under duedate1 in the initialization of assignment1. It says it cannot replace char type with "Date" which I defined as a struct with fields day and month. But as you can see in the .h file, QueData struct's 4th field is "Date". Despite this, why does it ask for char ?
I tried

```
    QueData assignment1 = { UserInput1, UserInput2, UserInput3, {UserInput4, UserInput5} };
```

too but it would say "too many initializer values".

However, if I do

```
QueData assignment1 = { "calc1", "hw5", 10, { 1, 11 } };
```

it works. How come when I change these values to variables it doesn't work?

Comment: Why not just initialize `duedate1` as `Date duedate1 = {1, 1};`, and then initialize `assignment1` using `duedate1` such as `QueData assignment1 = { " ", " ", 1, duedate1};`? Then further down once you have your input `duedate1` becomes `duedate1 = { UserInput4, UserInput5 };` and `assignment1` becomes `assignment1 = { UserInput1, UserInput2, UserInput3, duedate1 };`.

Comment: The problem with C compilers is that they get confused easily, and as a result the first error in the code can cause a cascade of nonsense errors. Which is to say that there is nothing wrong with `duedate1`, but you have at least 3 errors before you get to that point, and those three errors need to be fixed.

Comment: I just removed QueData assignment1 = { " ", " ", 1, { 1, 1 } }; if this is one of the errors. It was only for debugging. And if I do "QueData assignment1 = { "calc1", "hw5", 10, { 1, 11 } };" works but howcome when I change these values to variables it doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally a string literal like `"abc"` is treated as a pointer to a `char`. For example, the following code treats a string literal as a pointer

```
char *str = "hello";
printf( "%s\n", str );  // prints hello followed by a newline
```

However, if a string literal is used to initialize a character array, then according to the C11 specification

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string
>   literal or UTF−8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces.
>   Successive bytes of the string literal (including the terminating null
>   character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size)
>   initialize the elements of the array.

For example, the following code

```
char str[6] = "hello";
```

will put the characters of the string `"hello"` (followed by a `'\0'`) into the array.

However, this type of initialization only works for a string literal. You *cannot* initialize one array with the contents of another array. For example, the following is **not** valid

```
char str1[6] = "hello";
char str2[6] = str1;    // this is NOT allowed
```

The correct way to initialize `str2` is with a `strcpy`, e.g.

```
char str1[6] = "hello";
char str2[6];
strcpy( str2, str1 );
```

So the correct way to initialize `assignment1` is

```
Date duedate1 = { UserInput4, UserInput5 };
QueData assignment1 = { "", "", UserInput3, duedate1 };
strcpy( assignment1.courseName, UserInput1 );
strcpy( assignment1.assignName, UserInput2 );
```